# Electric field of infinitely extended flat plate

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

I am reading an example how to calculate the electric field of infinitely extended flat plate and I have trouble to understand certain steps

$$
E_{z}=\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{\sigma}{d^{2}} \cos \beta d \varphi r d r
$$

$$
E_{z}=\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{\sigma}{a^{2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \cos ^{3} \beta d \varphi r d r=\frac{1}{2 \epsilon_{0}} \frac{\sigma}{a^{2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos ^{3} \beta r d r
$$

$$
E_{z}=\frac{1}{2 \epsilon_{0}} \frac{\sigma}{a^{2}} \int_{0}^{\pi / 2} a^{2} \sin \beta d \beta=\frac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_{0}}\left.(-\cos \beta)\right|_{0} ^{\pi / 2}=\frac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_{0}}
$$
1. why is $ dA =rdrd\varphi $. I was thinking $dA = drd\varphi = rd\varphi + {\varphi}dr$

2. Why is the integral interval of $d\beta$ is from $0$ -> $\pi/2$ but not to $2\pi$[image]

Comment: 1) Look at the units of your proposed area element. Also note that $\text dr\text d\phi\neq\text d(r\phi)$ 2) Think about what $\beta$ is when your ring on the plate is very very large

Comment: This is really a maths question

Answer (score 1):

1. $dr d\varphi$ is different from $d(r\varphi)$. The expression for $dA$ comes from considering the tiny orange slice in the image. It has a length of $dr$ and a width of $rd\varphi$. (The difference in the widths goes to zero as you take $dr$ infinitesimally small.)
2. There has been a change of variables. You are no longer integrating in $r$, but in $\beta$. When $r$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, $beta$ goes from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.